# sql get the max 3 score rows for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data as follows:

```
cat score
a   80
c   88
b   36
b   96
d   99
b   76
d   89
a   50
d   69
b   36
d   59
b   96
b   86
c   98
a   50
a   90
c   83
b   66
```

How can I use SQL to get the max 3 score rows for each cat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: I agree that it is a duplicate. I'm not convinced that the thread cited offers the best example.

Comment: Note that you have no PRIMARY KEY - which may prove problematic further down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a correlated query :

```
SELECT tt.cat,tt.score FROM (
    SELECT t.cat,t.score,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable s FROM YourTable s
            WHERE s.cat = t.cat and t.score <= s.score) as cnt
    FROM YourTable t) tt
WHERE tt.cnt < 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT cat, score
FROM (
  SELECT cat, score,
         @seq := IF(@c = cat, @seq + 1,
                    IF(@c := cat, 1, 1)) AS seq
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c := '', @seq := 0) x
  ORDER BY cat, score DESC ) AS t
WHERE seq <= 3
```

Comment: Shurely shome mishtake ;-)

Comment: Fixed. But note that you may need to think about collations here, or run something like `SET NAMES utf8;` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union

```
(select cat, score 
from my_table
where cat='a'
order by score desc
limit 3)
union 
(select cat, score 
from my_table
where cat='b'
order by score desc
limit 3)
union 
(select cat, score 
from my_table
where cat='c'
order by score desc
limit 3)
union 
(select cat, score 
from my_table
where cat='d'
order by score desc
limit 3)
```